# Clustering website visitors by content groups using R

Tags: r, clustering

I am trying to cluster users based on the page categories they have visited in order to better understand the different user types. My data has the format:

userID;Category1;Category2;...;Category9

13123;1;0;...;1

If a user has been in a category, the value is 1, if not, it is 0. I have tried a few different approaches, e.g.:

```
library(cluster)
D=daisy(ga_new, metric='gower')
H.fit <- hclust(D, method="ward")
groups <- cutree(H.fit, k=3)
clusplot(ga_new, groups, color=TRUE, shade=TRUE,
         labels=5, lines=0, main= 'user segments')
```

[image: user segmentation]

After having read how to interpret the results, I am not too sure whether this has been the right approach, given that it is difficult to derive solutions here: what categories do the clusters now include?  Any suggestions how to approach this differently?

Comment: Have you considered [association rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning) as a means of clustering?

Comment: Aren't the categories already segments?

Comment: @lrnzcig, thanks for the suggestion, I will try that.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse, no because a user could be interested in more than one category, and I would like to find out which categories belong together. As an example, what other areas do users look at apart from the jobs section? Do we need to enhance the content there?

Answer (score 0):

After having tried several approaches, I guess the best approach for clustering users with respect to the content that they have viewed is using a hierarchical clustering. Plotting the data into a dendrogram will show the clusters that can be further analyzed by cutting.